# Is there any program to draw on the screen during full screen presentations via Zoom? Device: MacBook Air

Tags: pdf, keynote, fullscreen, drawing

I am holding a presentation and want to write (with a Wacom graphic tablet) on the screen while presenting. My slides are created in Keynote, but I can use the exported .pdf document as well.

So far I've tried the following:

- Presentation/fullscreen mode of Keynote/Adobe/standard Mac pdf viewer and trying to comment directly via Zoom
  **Problem**: instead of drawing, the next slide is displayed because my Mac thinks that I am clicking
  -- to circumvent this, I disabled advance on click in Keynote, but then I cannot even go to the next slide with my keyboard.
- Fullscreen mode of Adobe/standard Mac pdf viewer and trying to use the built-in comment function of Adobe/smpv
  **Problem**: I need to switch between presentation and drawing mode. And if I have a series of developing slides (i.e., where one bullet point becomes visible after the previous one) the drawing disappears (but I need the drawing displayed until all bullet points are displayed).

I don't have any iOS device for remote presentation. (Honestly, really annoying that you can't just use the necessary features with a Mac.)

Comment: And you can't just use a Zoom Whiteboard because... reasons?  https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/205677665-Sharing-a-whiteboard

Comment: I am giving a math talk and let's say one bullet point is a huge equation. Then I want to mark different parts of this equation and do some drawings for better understanding. So I really need to draw into the presentation itself.

A bonus would be that the drawing even stays on the slide after I proceeded with the presentation and go back

Comment: Have you considered moving the whole thing into Miro https://miro.com? It may have the tools you desire.